# How to perform cross join on datatables

Tags: c#, datatable, cross-join

i am to perform cross join (many to many relation) on datatables ( table1 X table2 X table3 X n tables).
this can be done using for/foreach loop or linq.. but dont know which one should i go for or any other option available..

Note: i am reading data from .xls files so can't go for sql queries..

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not an automatic way to make a cross join with datatables.

If I were you, I would go for Linq To Datasets.

Take a look to this MSDN How to. [Cross-Table Queries (LINQ to DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386969.aspx)